# Are questions about pinball on topic?

Tags: discussion

Are design questions related to pinball on topic here? I mean in terms of fun factor, layouts, scoring setups and the like not the actual physical tables since I'm working with a virtual one anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most (all?) questions on the site are about computer/video games.  I don't have a problem with it but you might get either no answers or maybe people complaining that it's off topic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we've got questions about virtual board games and no one says they're off-topic. This is either the same thing or even closer to video games, since physical pinball machines are basically video games. I don't understand the hate for pinball on Stack Exchange. :/

Comment: With all due respect, how is this an answer? He asked _exactly_ if this is in-topic, saying "people might complain it's off-topic" is kind of recursive...

Comment: @lohoris The site is community moderated. I'm just one guy with an opinion. It's entirely possible for community members to vote to close the question as off topic without any intervention from me. And if they do, I'll probably not reverse their decision. I'm just saying I wont close it outright because of the subject matter.

Comment: Sure, but there are some guidelines in every stack exchange, with the precise intent of determining what is and isn't in-topic.

Comment: Right. That's what we are doing now. I put out my opinion. People voted on my answer. Other people can feel free to make their own if they disagree. It's a fluid process.  Things that were formerly on topic are now not, and vice versa.